# How to send junit report via email as report doesn't display

Tags: html, junit, ant, report

I have a Junit HTML Report below in my local which is built through ANT:

Now the problem I am having is that if I try and attach this report by simply sending just the index.html, it will display this:

I want to know how can I send the above report via email so everyone can see the html report. I only want to send the index.html I don't want to send everybody the corresponding files.

The xml code to build this report is below (I xxx out some things which are not xxx in the real file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- WARNING: Eclipse auto generated file.
          Any modifications will be overwritten.
          To include a user specific buildfile here, simply create one in the same
          directory with the processing instruction <?eclipse.ant.import?>
          as the first entry and export the buildfile again. -->

<project basedir="." default="Test_Report" name="Test_Report">


<target name="xxx_SoapUI">
 <exec dir="." executable="C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0\bin\testrunner.bat">
 <arg line="-r -j -f 'D:\xxx\xxx' 'D:\xxx).xml'"></arg>
</exec>
</target>

    <target name="xxx_SoapUI">
 <exec dir="." executable="C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0\bin\testrunner.bat">
 <arg line="-r -j -f 'D:\xxx\xxx' 'D:\xxx).xml'"></arg>
</exec>
</target>

    <target name="xxx_SoapUI">
 <exec dir="." executable="C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.3.0\bin\testrunner.bat">
 <arg line="-r -j -f 'D:\xxx\xxx' 'D:\xxx).xml'"></arg>
</exec>
</target>


</project>
```

Comment: `testrunner.bat` must be in your `path`. Is it?

Comment: Have you checked the solutions?

Comment: Both solutions are good, I ended up using the noframes method so marked that as best answer but both answers will work. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `format="frames"`attribute normally generates separate files for frames and maybe stylesheets. As mentioned in the [task documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html), you can set the value to `noframes` and Ant will generate the report in a single HTML:

> The `noframes` format does not use redirecting and generates one file called `junit-noframes.html`.

In case you need to customize the XSL used to generate the report, you can override it using the `styledir` attribute (note that the file must be named `junit-noframes.xsl`). The default XSL is embedded in the Ant source code and can be viewed [here](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=ant.git;a=blob;f=src/etc/junit-noframes.xsl;h=fa3ac3e96b0f371a65deea4d157082115c2c04d7;hb=HEAD).

Answer (score 0):

Here is alternative approach.

In this approach, do not use any attachment of the test result. Instead, host the result in a container such as tomcat or WebDAV.

Here is the example for tomcat(should be something similar for WebDAV as well):

- Install tomcat
- Create a directory say `reports` under TOMCAT_HOME\webapps directory and make sure tomcat is started.
- After generating reports using current ant target, create new target for moving current reports under `TOMCAT_HOME\webapps\reports\<timestamp>`
- Send the reports link in the email. The report link could be `http://<hostname>:<port>/reports/<timestamp>/index.html`

This way, every one can access the report online.